# Program crashes with message "terminate called recursively" without throwing any exception

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, operator-overloading, undefined-behavior

I was making a simple C++ program using `CTable` - my custom class. `CTable` contains a pointer to an array of `int`, which can be resized and manipulated with `CTable` methods.

Here's a short snippet:

```
class CTable
{
 private:
  int *table; //pointer to the table
  int length; //length of the table
  ///...etc
 public:
  int SetLength(int length); //returns -1 on failure
  int SetValueAt(int index, int value); //returns -1 on failure
  ///...etc
  CTable& operator+=(CTable &other) //combine 2 CTables together
  {
        int oldLength = length;
        SetLength(length+other.GetLength());
        for(int i=oldLength;i<length;i++)
        {
            SetValueAt(i,other.GetValueAt(i-oldLength));
        }
        return *this;
  }
};
```

I also have another function that I use to split user input into words:

```
vector<string>* splitString(string sentence, char delim)
{
    vector<string> *res = new vector<string>();
    stringstream ss;
    ss.str(sentence);
    string word;
    while (getline(ss,word,delim))
    {
        res->push_back(word);
    }
    return res;
}
```

It is important to note that all the methods presented here seem to work fine on their own, i.e. when I test them individually.

As you can see I have also overloaded the `+=` operator. The problem is that whenever I use this operator, the next user input crashes the program when the `splitString()` function is called. The program crashes with the sole error message  "*terminate called recursively*". No exceptions is thrown, nothing. Only an error code [`0xC0000005`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx)

I can't really show you the entire code because the program got pretty big, currently about 1000 lines of code.  I try to fix this program for hours and I have no idea what's going on. Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: don't see a try catch block, how do you know it's not throwing? btw. terminate( ) is the indicator that it's throwing but you're not handling it `catch( ... )` could help you with overlooked exception types

Comment: I tried putting a try-catch over the entire main function and it caught nothing.

Comment: You're probably getting some kind of undefined behavior. There's not nearly enough code here to diagnose it. You'll probably need to step through the code with a debugger to narrow it down.

Comment: You will need to learn how to use a debugger, and various development tools. Nobody else on stackoverflow.com can do it for you. Just because a program crashes at a particular point, that doesn't mean that's where the bug is, the bug can be anywhere, and knowing how to use a debugger, and various memory analysis tools like valgrind, is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: also make sure you're not throwing an exception through any code compiled with -fno-exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows error code `0xC0000005` means `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.  This is typically caused by problem with pointers, out of bound array accesses, memory corruption and other serious issues.

The `splitString()` function looks ok, so it certainly not causes by itself the kind of behavior you're describing.

The `operator+=()` looks more suspicious.  The code itself seems ok,  but it makes assumptions that  `SetLength()` changes the length, reallocates the pointer, and copies all the existing values, all without any problem. Note by the way that this code doesn't handle special case such as doing `+=` on one self.

Unfortunately,  the signature of this function is `int SetLength(int length);`.  So the name of the parameter hides the name of the member `length`, which could cause some serious mismatches that could lead to buffer overflows or unchanged member `length` (unless you use `this->length` and `length` to make the difference between the two).

Finally, you are using raw pointers instead of smart pointers.  So you must ensure the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  If you don't, you will end-up with shallow copies which could also lead to UB  (when one of the object releases the memory that it's copy is still using).

Comment: You were right, somewhere in the setlength function i put this->length instead of length and it caused all the problems. Thank you, I was trying to fix this for hours and couldn't find the cause.

Comment: @AlanKalane good news! Would it be possible for the records to update your question with the code of `SetLength()` before you corrected it (in and edit section) ?  This would be helpful for future readers having similar problems.